# Grails + ClojureScript

Tags: grails, clojurescript

Right now I'm writing application with **Grails 3** in backend and **AngularJS** in frontend. The problem is that JavaScript really suck and I want to switch into ClojureScript.

Sadly I couldn't find any plugin (asset pipeline) for ClojureScript. Is there any prepared way to integrate it to my Grails 3 app?

Answer (score 0):

This one works.

Just add this dependency to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:clojure:2.0.0.RC2'
}
```

Comment: I want to use ClojureScript (in front end) not Clojure in backend.

Answer (score 0):

What is this here ?

Grails Asset Pipeline for Clojure Script:
https://github.com/magx2/clojure-script-grails-asset-pipeline-plugin

The project looks rather dated, but maybe it will help to start your own project.